# Getting error information out of a websocket connect on iPad

Tags: ipad, websocket

I'm trying to implement the websocket protocol and for some reason the iPad isn't cooperating with me. The iPad runs the [Hybi-00 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-00) and the problem lies somewhere in the handshake. I'm getting as far as reading the request and the following magic bytes and responding with what I believe is the correct reply. The iPad isn't agreeing with me and shuts down the connection.

The protocol handler is working for [Hybi-06](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-06), which is run by most modern browsers.

I'd really like some way to make the iPad tell my *why* it has decided to shut down the websocket connection so that I can fix the issue. Either that or getting chrome or some other browser to downgrade their websocket version to the same version that iPad supports so that I can get some sort of clue as to what is actually going on.

Is there any way to obtain this information?

Ok, so, even though it would be nice to have the actual error explained, here's the handshake:

```
GET /myurl HTTP/1.1
Upgrade:WebSocket
Connection:Upgrade
Host:my-host.com
Origin:https://my-host.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key1:1  QB  9 ,  $169780@8A`@4
Sec-WebSocket-Key2:3 160RhGi7mu  97*66br9
```

The following eight bytes is the key:

```
{byte[8]}
    [0]: 105
    [1]: 199
    [2]: 161
    [3]: 204
    [4]: 5
    [5]: 176
    [6]: 104
    [7]: 199
```

The server replies with this

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade:WebSocket
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Origin:https://my-host.com
Sec-WebSocket-Location:ws://my-host.com/
```

And the key

```
{byte[16]}
    [0]: 100
    [1]: 132
    [2]: 37
    [3]: 58
    [4]: 243
    [5]: 195
    [6]: 173
    [7]: 26
    [8]: 180
    [9]: 239
    [10]: 33
    [11]: 56
    [12]: 40
    [13]: 192
    [14]: 123
    [15]: 255
```

This is run over a HTTPS connection, so it's basically data from my debugger since I can't get wireshark properly configured to extract this for the life of me. As far as I can tell, the handshake keys are correct as well.

Comment: Can you post the handshake request your server receives and the response it sends please?

Comment: ...or your server's Hybi-00 handshaking code

Comment: It's very deeply buried and located in several different languages. Also, it's not all mine. I'm proxying a call to a different server and mucking about with the contents. I'm suspecting it's got to do with the host and origin somehow since the call actually works without proxying.

Comment: If you can't provide code, can you use wireshark to grab the handshake request/response?

Comment: I'll try to give it a shot. Need to find the iPad around here somewhere. Will take a while, but I'll get it

Comment: I'd like to point out that Mobile Safari on IOS 6 supports RFC 6455. I don't have the statistics, but my feeling is that most iPad users are already on IOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1828462.aspx/1).

As Cybear points out, I would recommend upgrading to iOS6. Current statistics show [around 60% of overall iOS users are on iOS6](http://iphoners.org/tag/ios-6-penetration-rate/).

Comment: If they'd allow me to force iOS6, I would do that. It would be cool however if I could actually make this work and find out why there seems to be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Hybi-06 is an version of the protocol that was just a specification, if i'm not wrong there was not any browser in fact implementing that version.  I think the most of the browsers went to Hybi-10 then for Hybi-17 ( Rfc6455), as you say iOS uses Hybi00 at the moment.  There are couple of servers supporting that particular handshake. I also know that there are a few supporting every single version of the drafts.

I run [XSockets.NET](http://xsockets.net), we chosen to support Hybi-00 and the RFC6455 version, as those are the protocols implemented in the browsers. (Safari still on Hybi00)

As in RFC6455 there is a sections regarding supporting Multiple Protocols ;

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-26

If you are implementing somthing, my recomendation is to do the RFC6455